# How to cancel subscription using RevenueCat in flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

I have implemented subscription using RevenueCat in flutter but RevenueCat have no documentation about canceling subscription.

Comment: Have you tried using its REST API for subscriber deletion? https://docs.revenuecat.com/reference#subscribersapp_user_id

Comment: @rickimaru Will this cancel's the subscription? I thought this only deletes the subscriber from Revenuecat database.

Comment: Can you check the list of subscribers? Maybe you can check the subscriber list after requesting the DELETE. Can you also check the "Unsubscribe Detected At"? https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/purchaserinfo

Comment: In iOS, we cannot cancel the subscription, but we can `showManageSubscriptions` to let the user cancel the subscription themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't allow developers to cancel or refund subscriptions on behalf of customers. For Android subscriptions you can use the REST API to refund the last purchase and it will immediately expire the subscription and remove entitlement access -- https://docs.revenuecat.com/reference#revoke-a-google-subscription

Deleting a subscriber won't cancel the subscription, they can trigger a Restore Purchase and re-sync their purchases with RevenueCat servers.